# Sony Xperia Tablet Z cannot paste into webmail in (Firefox)

Tags: firefox-for-android, sony-xperia-z, copy-paste

Strange problem here... I have COPIED a URL link from the browser and can paste this into Notepad, but when I go to my Hotmail account using Firefox, I cannot get any option to PASTE to appear.  Long press does nothing, and there are no options I can find to 'paste' the clipboard item.  Very frustrating, and help much appreciated

Comment: Use a different browser? I don't use Firefox so I'm not sure, but another browser would tell you if it's a restriction on Microsoft's side, or on the browser's.

Comment: Hi @RossC thanks for the reply.  We tried Google Chrome also, without success.  Not really keen on installing many browsers although I think you might be on the right track.  We have installed a free email manager to plug into hotmail - and that works - despite not solving the issue exactly

Comment: I'd imagine that it is Microsoft and how they have coded their email page. That's a bit annoying alright. You could post what you did as an answer and accept it, as it might help others. Also, you could pop MS an email about it, maybe they'll change it going forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the only solution turned out to be a workaround.  By using an email Application instead of a browser to manage emails, we are able to copy and paste as you would expect.